# Ejs doesn't displayo on plesk

Tags: node.js, ejs, plesk

I' ve made a website using node.js and ejs as a render engine. When I upload the website online on plesk I found out that the plesk doesn't display the ejs files. There is anything I can do to fix that?

Comment: include any errors you get please

Comment: I didn't get eny errors. If i incude an .html file on file manager on plesk it will display it in the broswer but it doesn't display the index.ejs

Comment: Hi and welcome. Please see this post to edit your question so the community can answer https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask